# Eager load all classes before routes.rb being loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to do some meta programming to dynamically define routes based on existing classes.

**My goal**: based on defined classes dynamically create proper routes.

Here is the code:

```
app/models/widget.rb

class Widget < ApplicationRecord
  mattr_reader :available_types
  class_variable_set(:@@available_types, {})

  def self.type
    available_types.key(name)
  end

  def self.register_type(key)
    @@available_types[key] = self
  end
end


app/models/widgets/a.rb
class Widget::a < Widget
  register_type :a
end


config/environments/development.rb
...
config.eager_load = true
...
```

Now when I open the console, and type: `Widget.available_types` I immediately can see: `{ a: Widget::A }`

So now I'm trying to create routes:

```
config/routes.rb
namespace :widgets do
  Widget.available_types.keys.each do |widget_type|
    resources widget_type.to_s.pluralize
  end
end
```

Unfortunately that is not working.

At this point when `routes.rb` file is loaded, `Widget.available_types` is empty.

Adding this change to `routes.rb` make it working but it's not a solution

```
config/routes.rb

Widget::A #manually call the class here. This makes code working but don't want that

namespace :widgets do
  Widget.available_types.keys.each do |widget_type|
    resources widget_type.to_s.pluralize
  end
end
```

So my question is: How to force rails to load all necessary classes before `routes.rb` file is loaded?

Comment: Which rails version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version of rails: 5.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At this point when routes.rb file is loaded, Widget.available_types is
>   empty.

I'm not seeing that. Your code seems to work fine for me once I change the name of the class from `Widget::a` to `Widget::Dog` to prevent a couple of errors. I also found that I had to kill my terminal window between code changes or else `rails c` would not reflect my code changes and sometimes would show that `Widget.available_types` was empty.

If I add a line to your `namespace` block in `routes.rb`:

```
  namespace :widgets do
    puts "[ME]: #{Widget.available_types}"  #<==== HERE

    Widget.available_types.keys.each do |widget_type|
      resources widget_type.to_s.pluralize
    end

  end
```

then do `rails s`, I see the following output in the server window :

```
~/rails_projects/myapp2018$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.4 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
[ME]: {:dog=>Widget::Dog (call 'Widget::Dog.connection' to establish a connection)}
...
...
```

That shows that `Widgets.available_types` is not empty. And in fact, if I enter the following url in my browser:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/widgets/dogs/show
```

I am taken to the view `views/widgets/dogs/show.html.erb`.  And if I comment out your namespace block in `routes.rb`, I get a routing error.  I think that demonstrates that your code successfully creates dynamic routes.

If I kill my terminal window, and then do `rails c`, I also see that `Widgets.available_types` is not empty:

```
$ rails c
[ME] Widgets.availabe_types: {:dog=>Widget::Dog (call 'Widget::Dog.connection' to establish a connection)}
Running via Spring preloader in process 22753
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.4)
2.4.0 :001 >
```

On the other hand, if I do:

```
$ rake routes
```

I get:

```
[ME] Widgets.availabe_types: {}
Prefix Verb URI Pattern                Controller#Action
       GET  /support(/*all)(.:format)  redirect(301, path: /contact/%{all})
       GET  /contact(/*path)(.:format) contacts#show
```

That does show that `Widgets.available_types` is empty.  I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Lool, thanks for that awesome debugging! I was mistaken then, as I tried the `rake routes` to see if routes are properly generated. Seems I learned a lot thanks to you ;)

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend you to Michael Lang's blog entry

http://codeconnoisseur.org/ramblings/creating-dynamic-routes-at-runtime-in-rails-4

His example uses a `load` method to add entries to your Appplication.routes and then uses a `reload` method to activate the new routings.

```
class DynamicRouter
  def self.load
    ComingSoon::Application.routes.draw do
      Page.all.each do |pg|
        puts "Routing #{pg.name}"
        get "/#{pg.name}", :to => "pages#show", defaults: { id: pg.id }
      end
    end
  end

  def self.reload
    ComingSoon::Application.routes_reloader.reload!
  end
end
```

Comment: This is amazing and really interesting position. It did helped with my problem and I made use of it even If I decided to go with simpler solution. However 7stud's answer was the one that deservers approval I really appreciate this one!